# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I started working on a project and recently started coding in React Native. I'm currently running into an issue that shows me an error when I try to click the "Submit" button which should take me to another screen. I tried many things but all without success.

**App.js**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Sliders from './screens/Sliders';
import SignUp from './screens/signUp';
import SignIn from './screens/signIn';
import ResetPassword from './screens/resetPassword';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Sliders">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Sliders"
          component={Sliders}
          options={{ 
            headerShown: false, // Hide the header on the Sliders screen 
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="SignUp" 
          component={SignUp}
          options={{
            headerBackVisible: false, // ide the back arrow on the SignUp screen
            headerTitle: 'Sign Up', // Set a custom header title for the SignUp screen
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#129990', // Header background color
            },
            headerTintColor: '#ffffff', // Header arrow color 
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: '#ffffff', // Text color in the header
            },
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="SignIn" 
          component={SignIn}
          options={{
            headerBackVisible: true, // ide the back arrow on the SignUp screen
            headerTitle: 'Sign In', // Set a custom header title for the SignUp screen
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#129990', // Header background color
            },
            headerTintColor: '#ffffff', // Header arrow color 
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: '#ffffff', // Text color in the header
            },
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="ResetPassword" 
          component={ResetPassword}
          options={{
            headerBackVisible: false, // ide the back arrow on the SignUp screen
            headerTitle: 'Reset Password', // Set a custom header title for the SignUp screen
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#129990', // Header background color
            },
            headerTintColor: '#ffffff', // Header arrow color 
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: '#ffffff', // Text color in the header
            },
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Sign In Screen**: ( In this screen when I click submit button it shows the error I mentioned above )

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleFacebookLogin = () => {
    // Implement your Facebook login logic here
  };

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    // Implement your Google login logic here
  };

  /*const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required('Email is required!').email('Enter a valid email address'),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required('Password is required')
      .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters long')
      .matches(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])/, 'Password must contain symbols and numbers'),
  });*/

  const handleFormSubmit = (values) => {
    // Implement form submission logic here
    console.log(values);

    navigation.navigate('Home');
  };

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.socialContainer}>
          <Button
            title="Connect with Facebook"
            buttonStyle={styles.SocialButtonFacebook}
            icon={
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name='facebook'
                size={28}
                color="#ffffff"
                style={styles.SocialIcon} />
            }
            iconLeft
            onPress={handleFacebookLogin}
          />

          <Button
            title="Connect with Google"
            buttonStyle={styles.SocialButtonGoogle}
            icon={
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="google"
                size={28}
                color="#ffffff"
                style={styles.SocialIcon} />
            }
            iconLeft
            onPress={handleGoogleLogin}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.dividerContainer}>
          <View style={styles.DividerHr} />
            <Text style={styles.DividerText}>OR</Text>
          <View style={styles.DividerHr} />
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.SignUpContainer}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              email: '',
              password: '',
            }}
            /*validationSchema={validationSchema}*/
            onSubmit={(values) => handleFormSubmit(values)}
          >
            {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched }) => (
              <>
                <TextInput
                  onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                  placeholder='Email address'
                  value={values.email}
                  style={styles.FieldInput}
                />
                {touched.email && errors.email && <Text style={styles.SignUpValidation}>{errors.email}</Text>}

                <TextInput
                  onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                  value={values.password}
                  placeholder='Password'
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  style={styles.FieldInput}
                />
                {touched.password && errors.password && <Text style={styles.SignUpValidation}>{errors.password}</Text>}
                
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.SignUpButton} onPress={(handleSubmit)}>
                  <Text style={styles.SignUpButtonText}>Continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.RessetPasswordButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ResetPassword')}>
                  <Text style={styles.RessetPasswordText}>Resset Password</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.LoginContainer}>
          <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')} style={styles.LoginText}>
            Don't have an account? Sign Up
          </Text>
        </View>
        
      </View>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

I have tried in every way to solve the problem, I don't even know what I have tried, can someone explain to me and give me a solution for the mentioned problem.

Comment: There's no home screen

Answer (score 0):

As Junius L Mentioned, you did not define Stack.Screen named "Home" in your Navigator.

You should think about your

```
<Stack.Navigator> </Stack.Navigator>
```

as container for your screens.
When you want to navigate within that navigator to a screen, that is not defined in it. You will get this message.

Bare in mind that even if you have screen defined with correct name, but it is not in navigator that you are currently in (not your case now, but might very well happen in future in more complex projects) this error will happen as well.
React navigation simply looks for Screen called "Home" and if it misses, you get this.
To fix your code add one and that should be it.

```
 <Stack.Screen
          name="Home" // <======== Define another Stack.Screen named Home
          component={HomeScreen} //<====== Your HomeScreen component
          options={{ 
            headerShown: false, // Hide the header on the Sliders screen 
          }}
        />
```

Comment: I tried this, that's how it works. However, when the user opens the Sign In screen and clicks on the submit button that should redirect him to the Home screen, it doesn't redirect him, doesn't throw any error, and the whole application freezes, so I have to exit all the screens to restart the whole system.

Comment: Well, it is up to you to debug your code further, maybe Home is expecting some props you don't send via navigation. 
As far as mentioned issue from title goes, considering provided code, i believe i proposed solution that is correct answer.